# Double (Nested) XLOOKUP with reverse search mode issue

Tags: google-sheets, nested, xlookup

I've created a profit/loss google sheet that allows me to price up a list of items for each project I'm working on (I've simplified it for the purpose of my issue I'm trying to solve). It works by referencing a master pricing sheet so that I can manage the current pricing from one location.

In the MasterCopy tab I'm importing the master pricing sheet for all my items. If you look at the first row, the first set of pricing for EUR, USD, AUD are my costs and the second set of those curriencies are my sell price.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SE-FtDsJOblrlEpkxSwn3_L3MZ1VD6DNzTDlGTj0vCc/edit?usp=sharing

In the "Profit Loss" sheet I'm using a nested XLOOKUP formula. For columns F, G, and H the formula uses "1" for the search mode and for columns K, L, and M it is the same, but uses "-1" search mode so that it searches across the MasterCopy sheet headers in reverse.

XLOOKUP(F$2,MasterCopy!$1:$1,xlookup($A3,MasterCopy!$A:$A,MasterCopy!$1:$1000),,,1)

XLOOKUP(K$2,MasterCopy!$1:$1,xlookup($A3,MasterCopy!$A:$A,MasterCopy!$1:$1000),,,-1)

However, the issue I run into is that for some reason one of the column sets (EUR, USD, or AUD cost and sell) it will show the same pricing for the cost and sell columns for the corresponding currency. For example, cell L3 shows 1,025 USD, but the corresponding USD cost column also shows 1,025 USD, when it should actually be a value of 925 (which is correctly showing in the MasterCopy tab).

Any help would be really welcomed. I'm hoping it's a simple logic error, but just can't seem to get all the sets of pricing to show the correct values.

Edit 1
I reloaded the sheet and suddenly it's the AUD columns showing the same values. See image below

[AUD columns showing same values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g66v0.png)

Comment: I'm seeing 925 in the cell you're saying you see 1025. Can you also post an image of what you're seeing?

Comment: Hi, sorry the error sometimes generates in the USD columns, but looks like it's now showing the same values in the AUD columns. The strange thing is that when I click on the cell and hit enter to reload the formula, it then shows the correct formula. However, when I reload the sheet, it goes back to showing both of either the SELL or COST for the corresponding currency... I've added a photo in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just use the header '**AUD Sell**' in Cell **AR1** (MasterCopy)
AND
use this formula in Cell **M3** (Profit Loss)

```
=XLOOKUP(M$2&" "&J$1,MasterCopy!$1:$1,xlookup($A3,MasterCopy!$A:$A,MasterCopy!$1:$1000),)
```

totally eliminating the search_mode which is causing this amiss.

Comment: I thought of that, but the formula in N3 joins the header of M2 and N2 to determine the exchange rate.

=if(J3=true,if(K$2=N$2,K3*1,K3*(query(GOOGLEFINANCE(join("","currency:",K$2,N$2), "close", datevalue($D$1))," select Col2 label Col2 '' ")))+....

I could always strip the "Sell", but I'm trying to avoid too many workarounds.